# Trying to add ppa repository to Debian fails with GPG error

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, gpg, ppa

I would like to install the package [sile](https://launchpad.net/%7Esile-typesetter/+archive/ubuntu/sile) on Debian. It is available on Ubuntu as a PPA. I located the url and added it to my `sources.list` file. Then I updated. However `sile` was not downloadable due to an error.

```bash
$ printf "deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic main\ndeb-src https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic main\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
$ sudo apt update
Get:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic InRelease [18.1 kB]
Err:15 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 904F67626F1CF535
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                          
W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 904F67626F1CF535
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/sile-typesetter/sile/ubuntu kinetic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is it really "insecure" and bad practice to do this? What should I do if I want to go ahead anyway?

Comment: You should add ppa repos with `add-apt-repository`. This usually also sets up the gpg-keys.